# How can I create a table of only the unique elements in a list so I can order the elements in terms of frequency?

Tags: r

I have tried running the code below, however it does not work as the arguments are not all of equal length.

```
sentence= "I like tea and I love coffee and biscuits"
    words = function(x) {
      txt = unlist(strsplit(x,' '))
      wl = list()
      for(i in seq_along(txt)) {
        wrd = txt[i]
        wl[[wrd]] = c(wl[[wrd]], i)
      }
      class(wl) <- "wordclass"
      return(wl)
    }
    summary.wordclass <- function(y) {
      cat("the frequency of words",names(sort(table(y), decreasing=TRUE)),"\n")
    }
    wordfreq=words(sentence)
    summary(wordfreq)
```

I want to get an output like

```
[1] "I"     "and"   "like"    "tea"   "love"   "coffee"
```

However, I am getting the error

> Error in table(y) : all arguments must have the same length

If anyone could help that would be great!

Comment: No, they aren't. Have a look at `wordfeq`. The list entries have different lengths.

Comment: Oh so the elements in the string have to be the same length to put into a table? Is there any way of doing this?

Comment: I'm not sure you are aware what `table` does and how it works.

Comment: I am reasonably new to R but I have used table() before and have had no trouble. I can only seeing one argument in the >names(sort(table(y), decreasing=TRUE) that being y?

Comment: You can reproduce the error like this: `table(list(1, 1:2))`. I can't help much more because I'm unsure what the intended result would be.

Comment: I suppose the intended result would be a table of the words in the wordfreq list to be ordered from most frequent occurring to least. I understand why table(list(1, 1:2)) is wrong as it is asking for a table of elements 1 to 2 when there is only 1 element in the first argument. Could you perhaps tell me what my arguments are? Because to me it looks like I just have 'wordfreq' which is a list of words and second argument is just asking for them to be ordered decreasing. I don't understand what the 'arguments of different length' are?

Comment: Your "arguments" are the list entries. Please *show* the expected output in the question.

Comment: Do you mean my arguments are: "I" "like" "tea" "and" "I" "love" "coffee" "and" "biscuits" ? I *still* don't understand why their differing lengths matters?

Comment: No, they are `$I [1] 1 5`, `$like [1] 2`, ... *Look* at `wordfreq`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

would

`names(sort(table(unlist(strsplit(sentence," "))),decreasing=T))`

work for you ?

the output is

`[1] "and"      "I"        "biscuits" "coffee"   "like"     "love"     "tea"`

Comment: Yes! Perfect! I'd been playing around with it for so long and couldn't understand why it wasn't working. Thank you so much!